# type 'TextEditingController' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am trying to signup the user but getting this error

**`type 'TextEditingController' is not a subtype of type 'String'`**

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart';
import 'package:get/get_navigation/get_navigation.dart';
import 'package:shoppingmart/common_widget/app_logo_widget.dart';
import 'package:shoppingmart/common_widget/bg_widget.dart';
import 'package:shoppingmart/common_widget/custom_textfield.dart';
import 'package:shoppingmart/common_widget/our_button.dart';
import 'package:shoppingmart/const/consts.dart';
import 'package:shoppingmart/const/List.dart';
import 'package:shoppingmart/controller/auth_controller.dart';
import 'package:shoppingmart/screens/auth_screen/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:shoppingmart/screens/home/home.dart';
import 'package:status_alert/status_alert.dart';

class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUp({super.key});

  @override
  State<SignUp> createState() => _SignUpState();
}

class _SignUpState extends State<SignUp> {
  bool isCheck = false;
  var controller = Get.put(AuthController());

  //text controllers
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController confirmPasswordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return bgWidget(
        child: Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
            body: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  (context.screenHeight * 0.1).heightBox,
                  applogoWidget(),
                  10.heightBox,
                  "Signup to $appname".text.white.fontFamily(bold).make(),
                  20.heightBox,
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      CustomTextField(
                          obsecuretext: false,
                          title: name,
                          hint: nameHint,
                          controller: nameController),
                      CustomTextField(
                          obsecuretext: false,
                          title: email,
                          hint: emailHint,
                          controller: emailController),
                      CustomTextField(
                          obsecuretext: true,
                          title: password,
                          hint: passwordHint,
                          controller: passwordController),
                      CustomTextField(
                          obsecuretext: true,
                          title: confirmPassword,
                          hint: passwordHint,
                          controller: confirmPasswordController),
                      Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                          child: TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              child: forgetPass.text.size(15).make())),
                      5.heightBox,
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Checkbox(
                            activeColor: redColor,
                            checkColor: whiteColor,
                            value: isCheck,
                            onChanged: (newValue) {
                              setState(() {
                                isCheck = newValue!;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                          5.widthBox,
                          Expanded(
                            child: RichText(
                                text: const TextSpan(children: [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: "I agree to the ",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: fontGrey, fontFamily: regular)),
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: termsandCondition,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: redColor, fontFamily: regular)),
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: " & ",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: fontGrey, fontFamily: regular)),
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: privacyPolicy,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: redColor, fontFamily: regular)),
                            ])),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      ourButton(
                          title: signup,
                          color: redColor,
                          textColor: whiteColor,
                          onPress: () async {
                            if (passwordController.text ==
                                confirmPasswordController.text) {
                              if (isCheck != false) {
                                try {
                                  await controller
                                      .signupMethod(
                                    context: context,
                                    email: emailController,
                                    password: passwordController,
                                  )
                                      .then((value) {
                                    return controller
                                        .storeUserData(
                                            name: nameController,
                                            email: emailController,
                                            password: passwordController)
                                        .then((value) {
                                      VxToast.show(context,
                                          msg: 'Account Created Sucessfully');
                                      Get.offAll(LoginScreen());
                                    });
                                  });
                                } catch (e) {
                                  VxToast.show(context, msg: e.toString());
                                  FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                                }
                              }
                            } else {
                              VxToast.show(context,
                                  msg: 'Confirm password should be same');
                            }
                          }).box.width(context.screenWidth - 50).make(),
                      5.heightBox,
                      RichText(
                          text: const TextSpan(children: [
                        TextSpan(
                            text: alreadyhaveanAccount,
                            style: TextStyle(color: fontGrey)),
                        TextSpan(
                            text: login,
                            style:
                                TextStyle(color: redColor, fontFamily: bold)),
                      ])).onTap(() {
                        Get.back();
                      })
                    ],
                  )
                      .box
                      .white
                      .rounded
                      .padding(const EdgeInsets.all(16))
                      .width(context.screenWidth - 60)
                      .shadowSm
                      .make(),
                ],
              ),
            )));
  }
}
```

**Error Log**

```
I/flutter ( 5199): type 'TextEditingController' is not a subtype of type 'String'
D/FirebaseAuth( 5199): Notifying id token listeners about a sign-out event.
D/FirebaseAuth( 5199): Notifying auth state listeners about a sign-out event.
I/flutter ( 5199): Color(0xdd000000)
```

Appreciate your answer

Comment: could you include storeUserData too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `.text` next to your `controllers`

example

```
.storeUserData(
  name: nameController.text
```

instead of

```
.storeUserData(
      name: nameController
```

and so with others `controllers` .

Comment: Appreciate your help but error is not resolved but evolved into another `TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'TextEditingController?')`

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart';
import 'package:get/get_navigation/get_navigation.dart';
import 'package:shoppingmart/common_widget/app_logo_widget.dart';
import 'package:shoppingmart/common_widget/bg_widget.dart';
import 'package:shoppingmart/common_widget/custom_textfield.dart';
import 'package:shoppingmart/common_widget/our_button.dart';
import 'package:shoppingmart/const/consts.dart';
import 'package:shoppingmart/const/List.dart';
import 'package:shoppingmart/controller/auth_controller.dart';
import 'package:shoppingmart/screens/auth_screen/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:shoppingmart/screens/home/home.dart';
import 'package:status_alert/status_alert.dart';

class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUp({super.key});

  @override
  State<SignUp> createState() => _SignUpState();
}

class _SignUpState extends State<SignUp> {
  bool isCheck = false;
  var controller = Get.put(AuthController());

  //text controllers
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController confirmPasswordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return bgWidget(
        child: Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
            body: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  (context.screenHeight * 0.1).heightBox,
                  applogoWidget(),
                  10.heightBox,
                  "Signup to $appname".text.white.fontFamily(bold).make(),
                  20.heightBox,
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      CustomTextField(
                          obsecuretext: false,
                          title: name,
                          hint: nameHint,
                          controller: nameController),
                      CustomTextField(
                          obsecuretext: false,
                          title: email,
                          hint: emailHint,
                          controller: emailController),
                      CustomTextField(
                          obsecuretext: true,
                          title: password,
                          hint: passwordHint,
                          controller: passwordController),
                      CustomTextField(
                          obsecuretext: true,
                          title: confirmPassword,
                          hint: passwordHint,
                          controller: confirmPasswordController),
                      Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                          child: TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              child: forgetPass.text.size(15).make())),
                      5.heightBox,
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Checkbox(
                            activeColor: redColor,
                            checkColor: whiteColor,
                            value: isCheck,
                            onChanged: (newValue) {
                              setState(() {
                                isCheck = newValue!;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                          5.widthBox,
                          Expanded(
                            child: RichText(
                                text: const TextSpan(children: [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: "I agree to the ",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: fontGrey, fontFamily: regular)),
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: termsandCondition,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: redColor, fontFamily: regular)),
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: " & ",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: fontGrey, fontFamily: regular)),
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: privacyPolicy,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: redColor, fontFamily: regular)),
                            ])),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      ourButton(
                          title: signup,
                          color: redColor,
                          textColor: whiteColor,
                          onPress: () async {
                            if (passwordController.text ==
                                confirmPasswordController.text) {
                              if (isCheck != false) {
                                try {
                                  await controller
                                      .signupMethod(
                                    context: context,
                                    email: emailController,
                                    password: passwordController,
                                  )
                                      .then((value) {
                                    return controller
                                        .storeUserData(
                                            name: nameController.text,
                                            email: emailController.text,
                                            password: passwordController.text)
                                        .then((value) {
                                      VxToast.show(context,
                                          msg: 'Account Created Sucessfully');
                                      Get.offAll(LoginScreen());
                                    });
                                  });
                                } catch (e) {
                                  VxToast.show(context, msg: e.toString());
                                  FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                                }
                              }
                            } else {
                              VxToast.show(context,
                                  msg: 'Confirm password should be same');
                            }
                          }).box.width(context.screenWidth - 50).make(),
                      5.heightBox,
                      RichText(
                          text: const TextSpan(children: [
                        TextSpan(
                            text: alreadyhaveanAccount,
                            style: TextStyle(color: fontGrey)),
                        TextSpan(
                            text: login,
                            style:
                                TextStyle(color: redColor, fontFamily: bold)),
                      ])).onTap(() {
                        Get.back();
                      })
                    ],
                  )
                      .box
                      .white
                      .rounded
                      .padding(const EdgeInsets.all(16))
                      .width(context.screenWidth - 60)
                      .shadowSm
                      .make(),
                ],
              ),
            )));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are providing actual TextEditingController objects to your AuthController methods (signupMethod & storeUserData).

It also seems like your AuthController methods (above) are expecting String values for those methods. You should rather provide the values like:

```
await controller.signupMethod(
 context: context,
 email: emailController.text,
 password: passwordController.text,
)
```

and

```
await controller.storeUserData(
 name: nameController.text,
 email: emailController.text,
 password: passwordController.text,
)
```